# Is jemalloc heap profiling tracking allocations only?

Tags: memory-leaks, jemalloc

I'm trying to solve some memory leaks, and I'm using jemalloc to dump heap profiles:
`MALLOC_CONF=prof:true,lg_prof_interval:30,lg_prof_sample:17`

Works as charm, but I don't know what I'm looking at :)

Does jemaloc [heap profiling](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Use-Case:-Heap-Profiling) show all (sampled) allocations, or just the ones that haven't been free()-ed at the moment of taking a dump? Or to put it differently: is it an allocation profile, or "live" blocks profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is by default, jeprof shows allocations that are "live" at the time the dump is written. You can change that however.

See the jeprofile `prof_accum` option if you want to record all allocations: http://jemalloc.net/jemalloc.3.html#opt.prof_accum

You may also need the `--alloc_space` jeprof flag to display allocated bytes instead of the in use ones: https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/blob/dev/bin/jeprof.in#L208